# Parsing using BeautifulSoup inner tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Still learning how to use BeautifulSoup, and I'm trying to scape some information from an NFL site using python3 and BeautifulSoup. I parsed the site as lxml:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
```

I then find all matchup information:

```
matchups = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "cmg_game_data cmg_matchup_game_box"})
```

At this point each matchup in the matchups list contains a lot of data and looks like this:

```
<div class="cmg_game_data cmg_matchup_game_box" data-away-conference="American Football Conference" data-away-team-city-search="Houston" data-away-team-fullname-search="Houston" data-away-team-nickname-search="Texans" data-away-team-shortname-search="HOU" data-competition-type="Week 1" data-conference="American Football Conference" data-event-id="80767" data-following="false" data-game-date="2020-09-10 20:20:00" data-game-odd="-10" data-game-total="54.5" data-handicap-difference="0" data-home-conference="American Football Conference" data-home-team-city-search="Kansas City" data-home-team-fullname-search="Kansas City" data-home-team-nickname-search="Chiefs" data-home-team-shortname-search="KC" data-index="0" data-last-update="2020-05-07T22:50:26.5700000" data-link="/sport/football/nfl/matchup/201993" data-sdi-event-id="/sport/football/competition:80767" data-top-twenty-five="false">
```

I want to specifically grab these inner classes (tags? attributes?) like data-away-conference and data-game-odd. How do I parse through this next level to extract these items? I've tried:

```
for matchup in matchups:
    awayconference = matchup.find("data-away-conference")
```

However this returns None. What is the proper way to extract these elements within <div class="cmg_game_data cmg_matchup_game_box"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]` to access tag's attributes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
    <div class="cmg_game_data cmg_matchup_game_box" data-away-conference="American Football Conference" data-away-team-city-search="Houston" data-away-team-fullname-search="Houston" data-away-team-nickname-search="Texans" data-away-team-shortname-search="HOU" data-competition-type="Week 1" data-conference="American Football Conference" data-event-id="80767" data-following="false" data-game-date="2020-09-10 20:20:00" data-game-odd="-10" data-game-total="54.5" data-handicap-difference="0" data-home-conference="American Football Conference" data-home-team-city-search="Kansas City" data-home-team-fullname-search="Kansas City" data-home-team-nickname-search="Chiefs" data-home-team-shortname-search="KC" data-index="0" data-last-update="2020-05-07T22:50:26.5700000" data-link="/sport/football/nfl/matchup/201993" data-sdi-event-id="/sport/football/competition:80767" data-top-twenty-five="false"></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

matchups = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "cmg_game_data cmg_matchup_game_box"})

for matchup in matchups:
    awayconference = matchup["data-away-conference"]  # or you can use matchup.get("data-away-conference")
    print(awayconference)
```

Prints:

```
American Football Conference
```